# icon replace from jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want if aria-expanded="true" the fa fa-plus icon  is replaced by  fa fa-minus icon
I have tried this with css and jquery but both of them doesnot work 
please help

```
1. From Css 



     .wpsm_panel-title > a[aria-expanded=true] i:before {
            content: "\f068" !important;
        }

2. From Jquery

<script>
if(this.attr('aria-expanded') === "true"){
    jQuery('.fa fa-plus').addClass('fa fa-minus').removeClass('fa fa-minus');
}    
</script>
```

Comment: `fa fa-plus` in this `fa` and `fa-plus` are two different classes. What you can do is try with specific element like this `jQuery('your-element-id-or-diffent-class').addClass('fa-minus').removeClass('fa-plus');`

Comment: is the element you're checking `aria-expanded` & the icon `fa fa-plus` different? if not better use `this` selector instead of `fa fa-plus` in jquery code.